# Custom validation rule in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a custom validation rule for laravel but I keep getting the following error:
`Method [validateOriginalAlt] does not exist.`

I have 2 classes.

FormValidator.php

```
abstract class FormValidator extends Validator
{

    protected $validator;
    protected $validation;
    protected $messages = [];
    protected $rules = [];

    function __construct(Validator $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }


    public function validate(array $formData)
    {
        $this->validation = $this->validator->make($formData, $this->getValidationRules(), $this->getValidationMessages());

        if ($this->validation->fails()) {
            throw new FormValidationException('Validation Failed', $this->getValidationErrors());
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function setRules($rules)
    {
        $this->rules = $rules;
        return $this;
    }

    protected function getValidationRules()
    {
        return $this->rules;
    }

    protected function getValidationMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }

    protected function getValidationErrors()
    {
        return $this->validation->errors();
    }
}
```

Show.php

```
class Show extends FormValidator
{

    protected $rules = [
        'title' => 'required|unique:shows,title',
        'slug' => 'unique:shows,slug',
        'flexget' => 'boolean',
        'airing' => 'boolean',
        'flexget_titles' => 'original_alt',
    ];


    public function validateOriginalAlt($string)
    {
        dd($string);
    }
}
```

In my controller I call the validation method like so:

```
    try {
        $this->showValidator->setRules([
            'title' => 'required',
            'slug' => 'unique:shows,slug,' . $id,
            'flexget_titles' => 'original_alt',
        ])->validate($data);
    } catch (Animekyun\Forms\FormValidationException $e) {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($e->getErrors())->withInput();
    }
```

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: It turns out I need to register my validation extension to the IoC container. Not sure how to do that in a clean way without using facades like in the docu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It turns out I need to register my validation extension to the IoC container. Not sure how to do that in a clean way without using facades like in the docu

The best place for such things is a [Service Provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0). You can use the existing `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` or create a new one (like `ValidatorServiceProvider`)

Anyways you should then register the validator in the `boot()` method of your provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['validator']->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
    {
        return new Show($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
    });
}
```

As you can see it's pretty much the same as with the Facade example from the docs. That's because a Facade is just an accessor to the underlying class, which can be accessed with `app['validator']`.

One last thing, consider renaming `Show` to something more expressive like `ShowValidator`.

### Update

For your case I'd suggest something like this:

```
class Show extends FormValidator {
    public function __construct(Validator $validator){
        $validator->extend('original_alt', 'Show@validateOriginalAlt');
        parent::__construct($validator);
    }
}
```

You could also do that in a service provider or globally, but that would mean that is available everywhere and I get the feeling you don't want that.

Comment: The problem I am facing now is that when the `Show` validator is instantiated, 4 arguments are passed. My `FormValidator` constructor only accepts the `Factory` class for the `Validator`.

And your last tip is a good one, I was already in the process of refactoring! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I see. What `Validator` class are you even extending? I personally have only done it like in the docs (extend `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`) and therefore inherit the constructor with those arguments....

Comment: I followed Jeffrey Way's tutorial on form validation and I'm extending `Illuminate\Validation\Factory`. The reason for that is because then I can actually `make` the validator and pass in my rules and messages

Comment: It is indeed! [I have to add more text or i can't comment]

Comment: The problem is that `$this->validator` is still the default `Validator` class and not your custom one with the `validateOriginalAlt()` method. Can you give me the link of that tutorial?

Comment: The tutorial is not free: https://laracasts.com/lessons/form-validation-simplified. As for the validator class that is not quite true (i think). The custom rule has to be registered for the validator to pick it up. But I think I am in essence saying what you just said. Hmm peculiar problem

Comment: I just quickly look through the source code [on github](https://github.com/laracasts/Form-Validation-Simplified) In the tutorial there is no custom rule like `validateOriginalAlt()` am I right?

Comment: That is correct, the tutorial doesn't cover adding custom rules.

Comment: It's a bit a tricky case but take a look at my updated answer... Hope it helps

Comment: I did something similar. I actually created a service provider where I registered that validation method the way you suggested. Works like a charm